# Why didn't Moses argue to spare lives of Midianites?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, moshe-rabbeinu, mattos

IIRC Avraham was praised for arguing with G-d about the fate of pious Sodomites asking G-d to spare their fate. G-d spared Lot and his family but the two cities were destroyed. Some speculate whether this was a metaphor for Lot's decision. Whether or not this is the case, the question remains.

I was thinking about a more general question about Moses wars, but decided to focus on the war on Midianites. What would happen if he [Moshe] were to follow Avraham's example [tradition]? He ought to at least ask G-d why not - Even though the Moabites were the main reason for this war G-d spared them all because of the potential that will come from them. Mosh Rabbeinu could have asked whether there is no such potential in Midianite.

Why didn't he?

Answer (score 3):

You should compare apples to apples, not to oranges.
Abraham wasn't in a war, while Moses was.
Actually, god wanted this raid to be an act of vengence, so maybe there is no place for mercy here.

Bameedbar 31 2

> נקם נקמת בני ישראל מאת המדינים אחר תאסף אל עמי

Avenge the vengeance of Israel from the Midianites, Afterwards you will die.